# cannot compile standalone asio with exceptions turned off

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to build project which uses standalone asio as dependency. Problem is that with exceptions turned off (`-fno-exceptions`), I have to define `throw_exception` function (link to [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/exception/doc/throw_exception.html)), but no matter how I define that function, linker throws `undefined reference`.
This is how I've tried to define `throw_exception`:

```
#define ASIO_NO_EXCEPTIONS
#include <asio/detail/throw_exception.hpp>

template <class E> 
void asio::detail::throw_exception(E const& e) {
// do something
}
```

I receive these linking errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `asio::detail::do_throw_error(std::error_code const&, char const*) [clone .isra.0]':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text+0x333): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<std::system_error>(std::system_error const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: _libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `void asio::execution::detail::any_executor_base::query_fn<void, asio::execution::prefer_only<asio::execution::detail::outstanding_work::tracked_t<0> > >(void*, void const*, void const*)':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_11prefer_onlyINS1_16outstanding_work9tracked_tILi0EEEEEEEvPvPKvSB_[_ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_11prefer_onlyINS1_16outstanding_work9tracked_tILi0EEEEEEEvPvPKvSB_]+0x28): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<asio::execution::bad_executor>(asio::execution::bad_executor const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `void asio::execution::detail::any_executor_base::query_fn<void, asio::execution::prefer_only<asio::execution::detail::outstanding_work::untracked_t<0> > >(void*, void const*, void const*)':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_11prefer_onlyINS1_16outstanding_work11untracked_tILi0EEEEEEEvPvPKvSB_[_ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_11prefer_onlyINS1_16outstanding_work11untracked_tILi0EEEEEEEvPvPKvSB_]+0x28): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<asio::execution::bad_executor>(asio::execution::bad_executor const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `void asio::execution::detail::any_executor_base::query_fn<void, asio::execution::prefer_only<asio::execution::detail::relationship::fork_t<0> > >(void*, void const*, void const*)':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_11prefer_onlyINS1_12relationship6fork_tILi0EEEEEEEvPvPKvSB_[_ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_11prefer_onlyINS1_12relationship6fork_tILi0EEEEEEEvPvPKvSB_]+0x28): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<asio::execution::bad_executor>(asio::execution::bad_executor const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `void asio::execution::detail::any_executor_base::query_fn<void, asio::execution::prefer_only<asio::execution::detail::relationship::continuation_t<0> > >(void*, void const*, void const*)':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_11prefer_onlyINS1_12relationship14continuation_tILi0EEEEEEEvPvPKvSB_[_ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_11prefer_onlyINS1_12relationship14continuation_tILi0EEEEEEEvPvPKvSB_]+0x28): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<asio::execution::bad_executor>(asio::execution::bad_executor const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `void asio::execution::detail::any_executor_base::query_fn<void, asio::execution::context_as_t<asio::execution_context&> >(void*, void const*, void const*)':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_12context_as_tIRNS_17execution_contextEEEEEvPvPKvSA_[_ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base8query_fnIvNS0_12context_as_tIRNS_17execution_contextEEEEEvPvPKvSA_]+0x28): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<asio::execution::bad_executor>(asio::execution::bad_executor const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o):sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base10require_fnINS0_12any_executorIJNS0_12context_as_tIRNS_17execution_contextEEENS1_8blocking7never_tILi0EEENS0_11prefer_onlyINS9_10possibly_tILi0EEEEENSC_INS1_16outstanding_work9tracked_tILi0EEEEENSC_INSG_11untracked_tILi0EEEEENSC_INS1_12relationship6fork_tILi0EEEEENSC_INSN_14continuation_tILi0EEEEEEEEvS8_EET_PKvSX_[_ZN4asio9execution6detail17any_executor_base10require_fnINS0_12any_executorIJNS0_12context_as_tIRNS_17execution_contextEEENS1_8blocking7never_tILi0EEENS0_11prefer_onlyINS9_10possibly_tILi0EEEEENSC_INS1_16outstanding_work9tracked_tILi0EEEEENSC_INSG_11untracked_tILi0EEEEENSC_INS1_12relationship6fork_tILi0EEEEENSC_INSN_14continuation_tILi0EEEEEEEEvS8_EET_PKvSX_]+0x2d): more undefined references to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<asio::execution::bad_executor>(asio::execution::bad_executor const&)' follow
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `asio::detail::scheduler::scheduler(asio::execution_context&, int, bool, asio::detail::scheduler_task* (*)(asio::execution_context&)) [clone .part.0]':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio6detail9schedulerC2ERNS_17execution_contextEibPFPNS0_14scheduler_taskES3_E.part.0[_ZN4asio6detail9schedulerC5ERNS_17execution_contextEibPFPNS0_14scheduler_taskES3_E]+0x228): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<std::system_error>(std::system_error const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `asio::detail::epoll_reactor::notify_fork(asio::execution_context::fork_event)':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio6detail13epoll_reactor11notify_forkENS_17execution_context10fork_eventE[_ZN4asio6detail13epoll_reactor11notify_forkENS_17execution_context10fork_eventE]+0x375): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<std::system_error>(std::system_error const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `asio::detail::scheduler::scheduler(asio::execution_context&, int, bool, asio::detail::scheduler_task* (*)(asio::execution_context&))':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio6detail9schedulerC2ERNS_17execution_contextEibPFPNS0_14scheduler_taskES3_E[_ZN4asio6detail9schedulerC5ERNS_17execution_contextEibPFPNS0_14scheduler_taskES3_E]+0x24a): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<std::system_error>(std::system_error const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio6detail9schedulerC2ERNS_17execution_contextEibPFPNS0_14scheduler_taskES3_E[_ZN4asio6detail9schedulerC5ERNS_17execution_contextEibPFPNS0_14scheduler_taskES3_E]+0x4f7): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<std::system_error>(std::system_error const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_socket.cpp.o): in function `asio::execution_context::service* asio::detail::service_registry::create<asio::detail::epoll_reactor, asio::execution_context>(void*)':
sio_socket.cpp:(.text._ZN4asio6detail16service_registry6createINS0_13epoll_reactorENS_17execution_contextEEEPNS4_7serviceEPv[_ZN4asio6detail16service_registry6createINS0_13epoll_reactorENS_17execution_contextEEEPNS4_7serviceEPv]+0x5d6): undefined reference to `void asio::detail::throw_exception<std::system_error>(std::system_error const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_client_impl.cpp.o): in function `std::_Function_handler<void (bool, std::shared_ptr<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const> const&), sio::client_impl::on_ping()::{lambda(bool, std::shared_ptr<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const>)#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, bool&&, std::shared_ptr<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const> const&)':
sio_client_impl.cpp:(.text+0x3c40): undefined reference to `websocketpp::endpoint<websocketpp::connection<websocketpp::config::asio_client>, websocketpp::config::asio_client>::send(std::weak_ptr<void>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, websocketpp::frame::opcode::value)'
/usr/bin/ld: libsioclient.a(sio_client_impl.cpp.o): in function `sio::client_impl::connect_impl(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
sio_client_impl.cpp:(.text+0x988c): undefined reference to `websocketpp::connection<websocketpp::config::asio_client>::replace_header(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

How to properly define `throw_exception` function or if I'm missing something, how can these errors be solved?

Comment: Why would you want to run asio without exceptions? I'm not even sure that's possible at all.  It's not only about boost exceptions, the asio library depends on many stl containers and algorithms, and depends on stl to throw exceptions, i.e.: the code does not check for errors beyond the very occasional exception guard.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Yes, it's possible according to boost documentation, docs provide preprocessor definitions for boost in general and for standalone asio, but there's need to provide `asio::detail::throw_exception` or `boost::throw_exception` if using boost (asio/detail/throw_exception.hpp), because if `ASIO_NO_EXCEPTIONS` is set, `throw_exception` is only declared, not defined. I have to use websocketpp (which uses asio) in project, where exceptions are disabled, so I can't turn them on. Websocketpp provide exception-free mode, but I have to define that asio function to work with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution. Problem was that compiler threw implementation of `throw_exception` from code while compiling, and when linker tried to find that function, there simply was no `throw_exception`. I made it like this:

```cpp
namespace asio::detail {

    template <typename Exception> void throw_exception(const Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Something went wrong..." << std::endl;
        std::terminate();
    }
}; // namespace asio::detail
```

If I call this function somewhere, I don't receive linking errors. Probably, I have to implement some kind of error handling instead of that and find a solution to make this function properly compiled and linked, but, at least, I've found a reason of that strange behaviour.

Comment: THX !! I was thinking about dropping ASIO for an other library !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, log() is *the* imaginary function you already use for logging ...

```
// somechere in a cpp file, preferably.

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// ...

namespace boost::asio::detail {

template<>
void throw_exception(const asio::execution::bad_executor& e)
{
    // throw e;  // this is what the original function does
    LOG("asio::execution::bad_executor thrown\n");   // etc...
    exit(3);     // That's all you can do at this point.
}

template<>
void throw_exception(const std::system_error& e)
{
    LOG("std::system_error thrown\n");  // etc...
    exit(3);     // That's all you can do at this point.
}

}
```

You may need to declare more specializations as you go along.